# Onto and one-to-one linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

My book seems a bit unclear about onto and one to one linear transformations. Here is the excerpt:

[image]

and this is what I understand to be the rank of T:

[image]

rank(T) = dimension of column space of the original matrix.

Is the rank of T not the same thing as the dimension of W? Are these not the same thing? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Hint: column space IS the range.

Comment: What is the confusion?

Comment: @AndresMejia what is the dimension of W? How is it diff from the rank(T)?

Comment: Consider the function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R x \mapsto 0$ . Here the dimension of W is 1, but the dimension of the image is 0 (which is the rank.) in the case where the two numbers coincide, the map is said to be onto (surjective)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is R? Rx is just the space of 1-tuple vectors right? Why is the dimension 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank of $T$ is the number of leading $1$'s. It is just a number that apriori has nothing to do with dimensions.

It turns out that the corresponding vectors form a basis for $W:=Im T$, this is in fact a proof of the theorem you are talking about (Theorem 6.7).

Since these two are equivalent, often we tend to ignore the original definition and think of them as the same (this leads to the confusion in the last paragraph).

Comment: But W is the set of images right? It's the result of the transformation of the domain right?

Comment: What two are equivalent?

Comment: @Jwan622 The rank is always equal to the dimension of the image. The "two" are the rank and the dimension of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course for any matrix the dimension of $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ is equal the dimension of $\operatorname{Row}(A)$ and that number is by definition $\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

Therefore if $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ is equal to the dimension of $W$ it means that the set "columns of $A$" contains a basis for $W$ and therefore the transformaion is onto.